# not able to edit values in website navbar in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

i have a website build in wordpress, the url for the website is like this:

[enter link description here](http://yantraev.com/)

i have imported demo contents for the theme and i am able to edit the page content except header section where there is the top bar, logo and menu. i tried using ftp but when i acces the header page its showing like this:

```html
<?php

    efuel_the_pageloader_overlay();
    get_template_part( 'navbar' ); 

    $pageheader_layout = efuel_get_pageheader_layout();
    $efuel_header_class = efuel_get_pageheader_class();

    if ( $pageheader_layout != 'disabled' ) : ?>
    <header class="page-header  <?php echo esc_attr($efuel_header_class); ?>">
        <div class="container">   
            <?php
                efuel_the_h1();         
                efuel_the_breadcrumbs();
            ?>      
        </div>      
    </header>
```

is there anyway to fix it ot is there anyway or plugin to edit the topbar and logo in wordpress, thanks in advance

Comment: did you try reading the theme documentation? [check it here](http://efuel.like-themes.com/documentation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have to see the customizable options the theme offers specifically, but in general, the header menu nav items are controlled within the Appearance > Menus section of the admin.

The logo and top bar, depending on the theme, will be located in the Appearance > Customize > Header section

Comment: in menus section there is only the navigation like home,about etc. there is not topbar section

Answer (score 0):

According to [the theme documentation](http://efuel.like-themes.com/documentation/#section-5) you have to go to `Appearance -> Theme Settings` on the Header tab. You should find everything you need there